# Use Backendless behind proxy

Tags: java, http-proxy, backendless

I'm trying to use [Backendless](https://backendless.com/) framework in my Java server but I'm working behind a corporative http proxy and I get `UnknownHostException` when I do things like:

```
Backendless.Persistence.save(employee);
```

I have tried to put `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` JVM options but I still get the same error. I have tried with `java.net.useSystemProxies`, too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to make simpe Java UrlConnection to `api.backendless.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Backendless allows you to set custom endpoint using following signature:

```
Backendless.setUrl( "http://your-custom-endpoint-here" );
```

Then you set up port forwarding to redirect all requests from your mirror to `api.backendless.com`